# Xamarin iOS release automatic provisioning - none of the currency installed provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have read and tried all the fixed associated with releasing and app to the App Store, but I cannot find any suitable fix. I have setup an iOS developer account and created account, I have setup Xamarin to automatic provisioning but I am getting the error message "none of the currency installed provisioning profile". I have tried the following

1. Upgrade Xamarin and X Code
2. Change all Bundle Identifiers to the same
3. Delete all the certificates from the KeyChain
4. Restarted MacBook
5. Switched from Manual to Automatic bundles
6. Created a test app
7. Removed certificates from iOS account
8. Rebuild, cleaned, achieved the project several times

I just cannot resolve this problem, any help would be highly appreciated as it's driving me around the bend to release the app into the App Store.

Many thanks

6. [image]

Comment: is your bundle id really "com.companyname.test"?  Have you created a App Stor provisioning profile in the dev portal?

Comment: It was a fresh test app, so just called it a default. Do have provisioning profiles development and App Store proifle

Answer (score 0):

You should use manual provisioning instead of automatic provisioning when releasing your app to app store.

From the official document about publishing iOS app to App Store:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store

In the release build steps:

> 11. Navigate to the iOS Bundle Signing tab. Make sure that Configuration
>     is set to Release, Platform is set to iPhone, and that **Manual
>     Provisioning** is selected.

Of course you will need to have the corresponding distribution certificate and distribution provisioning profile created in Apple Developer page.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the help, I managed to resolve the problem with the following setups

1. Update all packages
2. Removed x-works (it was the latest version any way)
3. Re-install x-works
4. Delete all relating certificates in Keychain
5. Delete any certificates, profiles etc in app development site
6. Re-start Xamarin and MacBook (in the end did this several times)
7. Log out of Apple account in Xamarin
8. Re-log back into the Apple account in Xamarin
9. Setup auto provisioning in Xamarin i..e dev, dist etc and created the appropriate certificates
10. Generate a certificate within keychain using iOS account details
11. Plugged in iPhone and rebuilt the complete project
12. Achieved the build
13. Now it connected to the App Store and released the app

I am pretty sure you don't need to do all these steps, but seems like it took it back to the start of setting up Xamarin for app releasing. One problem might have been multiple certificates in KeyChain which caused the problem.

Many thanks for all the help and support.